# How to get rid of brackets in my citation using rmarkdown and biblatex

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown, biblatex

i'm an absolute beginner in RMarkdown und Latex. So, this is my first time trying to write a paper. I've got a template from my university which I use, but I have a problem with the citation. I want to use an apa style, which works very well in the bibliography. However the citation has brackets around the date and looks like this:

(Behrendt et al. (2016), S.1)

How get i rid of the brackets around the date? Thanks in advance!

My YAML-Header looks like this:

```
---
geometry: "a4paper,top=2cm,bottom=2cm,left=3.5cm,right=2cm"
fontsize: 12pt
linestretch: 1.5
automark: yes
indent: true
toc: false
classoption:
  - DIV=calc
  - headsepline=true
KOMAoptions:
  - headings=standardclasses
  - DIV=last  
table_caption: true
figure_caption: true
includes:  
  in_header: figure_placement.tex 
link-citations: yes
knit: "bookdown::render_book"
output:
  bookdown::pdf_book:
    includes:
      in_header: tex/praeambel.tex
    keep_tex: yes
    latex_engine: pdflatex
citation_package: biblatex
bibliography: bib/literatur.bib
biblio-style: apa
---
```

And my .bib entry looks like this:

```
@techreport{behrendtStrategieanalytischeBetrachtungFuer2016,
    address = {Berlin},
    type = {Inputpapier},
    title = {Strategieanalytische {Betrachtung} fÃ¼r eine {Green} {Economy}},
    language = {de},
    institution = {izt - Institut fÃ¼r Zukunftsstudien und Technologiebewertung},
    author = {Behrendt, Siegfried and GÃ¶ll, Edgar and Korte, Friederike},
    year = {2016},
    pages = {37}
        }
```

EDIT: Solution is to use square brackets [] instead of parentheses ()

Answer (score 1):

I focused way too much on my header. The problems is in the brackets I use in my citation. I used ( ) instead of [ ]. That was the problem.

Comment: Can please you edit this solution and add the version that works as desired?